Norm of differential of $\exp_p(s\cdot c(t))$ is constant (in proof of Gauss lemma for manifold)
Let $(M,g)$ a Riemann manifold with $\nabla$ Levi-Civita connection. $p\in M$ and $0<r<\text{inj}(p)$ (the injective radius). Let $c:[a,b]\to T_pM$ a curve with $|c(t)|=r \ \forall t\in[a,b]$. And define the map $F:[0,1]\times [a,b]\to M, F(s,t)=\exp_p(s\cdot c(t))$. Let $(s,t)$ be stanrdard coordinate on $[a,b]\times [0,1]$. I want to show that $g(F_*\partial_s,F_*\partial_s)=r^2$. Is there any way to do this?
My idea is try to show that $F_*\partial_s\big|_{(s,t)}=c(t)$ (though, this is impossible, because they are tangent vectors in different point, but I can only try this to get some relationship between $\|F_*\partial_r\|$ and $\|c(t)\|=r$). For this I use a normal coordinate around $p$, denote it by $(U,x=x_1,...,x_n)$, then $\forall f\in C^\infty(M)$:
$$
F_*\partial_s\big|_{(s,t)}(f)=\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\bigg|_{(s,t)}f\circ x^{-1}(s\cdot c(t)_1,...,s\cdot c(t)_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial(f\circ x^{-1})}{\partial x_i}\bigg|_{x\circ F(s,t)}c(t)_i
$$
where $c(t)_i$ are the components in orthonormal basis (used for normal coordinate) of $T_pM$. On the other hand,
$$
c(t)f=\sum_{i=1}^nc(t)_i\frac{\partial(f\circ x^{-1})}{\partial x_i}\bigg|_p
$$
These expressions looks similar, but obviously not the same, because the point which we take the value of the partial derivative is different. $p=x\circ F(s,t)$ only when $s=0$, but here $s$ is arbitrary. Is there some ideas?
Tip: This problem origins from a proof for Gauss Lemma, which states that $g(F_*\partial_s,F_*\partial_t)=0$. What I want to prove is just a step: $\frac{d}{dt}g(F_*\partial_s,F_*\partial_s)=0$. A background text is page 200, "Introduction to differential geometry" by Robbin,Salamon.

How did a curve $c(t)$ turn into a vector field?

@TedShifrin for fixed $t, \ c(t)$ is a tangent vector in $T_pM$, not vector field

But then you're writing $F_*\partial_s = c(t)$? Where does this live?

That's a false idea, and my calculations also shows it's not possible. I write this because this is only what I can think that there should be some relationship so that the norm of $F_*\partial_s$ and the norm of $c(t)$ (which is r) can be the same.

Titel: replace "guass" by "Gauß".

We have
$$
(F_*\partial_s)_{s_0}(t) = F_{*,(s_0,t)}\partial_s(s_0,t) = (\gamma_t)_{*,s_0}(\partial_s)_{t}(s_0) = \dot\gamma_{t}(s_0).
$$
Since $\gamma_t: s \mapsto F(s,t)$ is a geodesic, the length of its velocity $\dot\gamma_t \in \Gamma_{\gamma_t}(TM)$ is a constant. That is,
$$
\|\dot\gamma_t(s_0)\| = \|\dot\gamma_t(0)\|.
$$
Since $\gamma_t(0) = F(0,t) = p$, we have $\dot\gamma_t(0) \in T_pM$. Noticing that $(\exp_p)_{*,0} = \text{id}_{T_pM}$ and $\gamma_t = \exp_p \circ (s \cdot c(t))$, we can use the chain rule to calculate $\dot\gamma_t(0)$:
\begin{align*}
    \dot\gamma_t(0) &= (\gamma_t)_{*,0}(\partial_s)_t(0) = (\exp_p \circ (s \cdot c(t)))_{*,0}(\partial_s)_t(0) = (\exp_p)_{*,0\cdot c(t)}\underbrace{\left( (s \cdot c(t))_{*,0}(\partial_s)_t(0)\right)}_{\in T_0(T_pM)\cong T_pM} \\
    &= (\exp_p)_{*,0}\left((c(t))\big|_{s=0}\right) = \text{id}_{T_pM}(c(t)) = c(t).
\end{align*}
Here we have identified $T_0(T_pM) \cong T_pM$. Now we can finally use the condition $\|c(t)\| = r$:
$$
g((F_*\partial_s)_{s_0}(t),(F_*\partial_s)_{s_0}(t)) = \|(F_*\partial_s)_{s_0}(t)\|^2 = \|\dot\gamma_t(s_0)\|^2 = \|\dot\gamma_t(0)\|^2 = \|c(t)\|^2 = r^2.
$$
